# HTML Elements (tr &td) are showing on the client side

Tags: javascript, html, htmlelements

This is my first question on stack overflow, so I hope that I'm doing this correctly!

I'm working with pulling some data from an API, and then displaying that data in a table. So far my table is showing the HTML elements of `<tr><td> + </tr></td>`

Here is a photo to show my issue :

[Photo of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYaoD.png)

Here is the code that I'm using :

```
const fetchUserz = async() => {
  const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`);
  const data = await response.json();

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let table = document.getElementById(`myTable`);
    let row = `<tr>
 <td>${data[i].name}</td>
 <td>${data[i].email}</td>
 </tr>`;
    table.innerHTML += row;
    table.append(row);
  }
}

fetchUserz();
```

Here is the HTML :

```
<body class="text-white bg-secondary mb-3 bg-gradient" id="body">


 <main>
    <header id="head">
      <h2>API Project</h2>


  </header>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>


 <th> Names of People </th>
    <th> Emails of People </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

```js
const fetchUserz = async() => {
  const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`);
  const data = await response.json();
  // console.log(data)

for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  let table = document.getElementById(`myTable`);

 let row = `<tr>
  <td>${data[i].name}</td>
  <td>${data[i].email}</td>
  </tr>`;


  table.innerHTML += row;
  table.append(row);
}


}

fetchUserz();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset = "UTF-8">
  <title>Native Awakenings</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.html">Native Awakenings</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="about-me.html" class="nav-link">About Me</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Concious Creations
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="blog-posts.html">Blog Posts</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="offerings.html">Offerings</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="podcasts.html">Podcasts</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="yoga-videos.html">Yoga Videos</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://gitlab.com/Gregg-Hendrix/how-i-became-a-software-engineer" target="_blank">How I Became A Software Engineer</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <span class="navbar-text">
        May Presence Be Our Purpose
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<body class="text-white bg-secondary mb-3 bg-gradient" id="body">
  <main>
    <header id="head">
      <h2>API Project</h2>
    </header>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th> Names of People </th>
        <th> Emails of People </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

    <tbody id="myTable">

    </tbody>
  </main>
  <footer class="card-footer bg-dark bg-gradient navbar-dark text-light" id="footer"> If you want to support Native Awakenings, please do one kind act! Remember that you are unconditionally loved. My social media: Insta:<a href="https://www.instagram.com/greggyogi/" target="_blank"> @Greggyogi</a>, Email: gregg@gregghendrix.com, Facebook:<a href="https://www.facebook.com/gregg.hendrix.129" target="_blank"> Gregg Hendrix</a></footer>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="/js/weather.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I've also added a snippet of EVERYTHING, any help would be massively appreciated :).

Comment: You are calling `table.append(row);` right after doing `innerHTML+=row`. You are already adding the row to the table with the `+=` no need to do the append, which since you are passing it a string instead of an element is appending a textnode

Comment: I can confirm the previous comment. Remove `table.append(row);` and all will be good. This was easy to diagnose because you provided the snippet. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

You immediate problem is using both `innerHTML` and `append` as covered in the comments

Let's go with `innerHTML`...

It's probably better to create your HTML string in one go rather than `el.innerHTML += ...`. My gut feeling it that `.innerHTML +=` will have pretty bad performance as each round will require an HTML parse and an HTML serialize.

```
const table = document.getElementById(`myTable`);
const rows = data.map(d=>`<tr>
    <td>${data[i].name}</td>
    <td>${data[i].email}</td>
  </tr>`);
table.innerHTML = rows.join("");
```

Comment: Wow, thank you SO much! Removing table.append(row), worked! Thank you also @spender for going over and above, and helping my website have better performance. This was so valuable to me, and I feel deep gratitude for you all! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can create your HTML string as below.

```js
   
const fetchUserz = async() => {
  
const data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
    },
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "anastasia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Clementine Bauch",
    "username": "Samantha",
    "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
    "address": {
      "street": "Douglas Extension",
      "suite": "Suite 847",
      "city": "McKenziehaven",
      "zipcode": "59590-4157",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-68.6102",
        "lng": "-47.0653"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
    "website": "ramiro.info",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Jacobson",
      "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface",
      "bs": "e-enable strategic applications"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Patricia Lebsack",
    "username": "Karianne",
    "email": "Julianne.OConner@kory.org",
    "address": {
      "street": "Hoeger Mall",
      "suite": "Apt. 692",
      "city": "South Elvis",
      "zipcode": "53919-4257",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "29.4572",
        "lng": "-164.2990"
      }
    },
    "phone": "493-170-9623 x156",
    "website": "kale.biz",
    "company": {
      "name": "Robel-Corkery",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-tiered zero tolerance productivity",
      "bs": "transition cutting-edge web services"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Chelsey Dietrich",
    "username": "Kamren",
    "email": "Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca",
    "address": {
      "street": "Skiles Walks",
      "suite": "Suite 351",
      "city": "Roscoeview",
      "zipcode": "33263",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-31.8129",
        "lng": "62.5342"
      }
    },
    "phone": "(254)954-1289",
    "website": "demarco.info",
    "company": {
      "name": "Keebler LLC",
      "catchPhrase": "User-centric fault-tolerant solution",
      "bs": "revolutionize end-to-end systems"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Mrs. Dennis Schulist",
    "username": "Leopoldo_Corkery",
    "email": "Karley_Dach@jasper.info",
    "address": {
      "street": "Norberto Crossing",
      "suite": "Apt. 950",
      "city": "South Christy",
      "zipcode": "23505-1337",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-71.4197",
        "lng": "71.7478"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-477-935-8478 x6430",
    "website": "ola.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Considine-Lockman",
      "catchPhrase": "Synchronised bottom-line interface",
      "bs": "e-enable innovative applications"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Kurtis Weissnat",
    "username": "Elwyn.Skiles",
    "email": "Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Rex Trail",
      "suite": "Suite 280",
      "city": "Howemouth",
      "zipcode": "58804-1099",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "24.8918",
        "lng": "21.8984"
      }
    },
    "phone": "210.067.6132",
    "website": "elvis.io",
    "company": {
      "name": "Johns Group",
      "catchPhrase": "Configurable multimedia task-force",
      "bs": "generate enterprise e-tailers"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Nicholas Runolfsdottir V",
    "username": "Maxime_Nienow",
    "email": "Sherwood@rosamond.me",
    "address": {
      "street": "Ellsworth Summit",
      "suite": "Suite 729",
      "city": "Aliyaview",
      "zipcode": "45169",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-14.3990",
        "lng": "-120.7677"
      }
    },
    "phone": "586.493.6943 x140",
    "website": "jacynthe.com",
    "company": {
      "name": "Abernathy Group",
      "catchPhrase": "Implemented secondary concept",
      "bs": "e-enable extensible e-tailers"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Glenna Reichert",
    "username": "Delphine",
    "email": "Chaim_McDermott@dana.io",
    "address": {
      "street": "Dayna Park",
      "suite": "Suite 449",
      "city": "Bartholomebury",
      "zipcode": "76495-3109",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "24.6463",
        "lng": "-168.8889"
      }
    },
    "phone": "(775)976-6794 x41206",
    "website": "conrad.com",
    "company": {
      "name": "Yost and Sons",
      "catchPhrase": "Switchable contextually-based project",
      "bs": "aggregate real-time technologies"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Clementina DuBuque",
    "username": "Moriah.Stanton",
    "email": "Rey.Padberg@karina.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kattie Turnpike",
      "suite": "Suite 198",
      "city": "Lebsackbury",
      "zipcode": "31428-2261",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-38.2386",
        "lng": "57.2232"
      }
    },
    "phone": "024-648-3804",
    "website": "ambrose.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Hoeger LLC",
      "catchPhrase": "Centralized empowering task-force",
      "bs": "target end-to-end models"
    }
  }
]

  let table = document.getElementById(`myTable`);  
      
       for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
          let row = '';
             row +='<tr>';
             row +='<td>'+data[i].name+'</td>';
             row +='<td>'+data[i].email+'</td>';
             row +='</tr>';
          table.innerHTML += row;
       }
}

fetchUserz();
```

```html
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
       <th> Names of People </th>
       <th> Emails of People </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
   <tbody id="myTable">

    </tbody>
      <tbody id="myTable2">

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for this dynamic usage and generation of the table! I really appreciate this, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    const fetchUserz = async() => {
  const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`);
  const data = await response.json();
  // console.log(data)

for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  let table = document.getElementById(`myTable`);

 let row = `<tr>
  <td>${data[i].name}</td>
  <td>${data[i].email}</td>
  </tr>`;


  table.innerHTML += row;
  
}


}

fetchUserz();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).